# Как вытащить все вхождения после словосочетания через регулярные выражения?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть исходный текст такого вида:

```
{"html":"\u003cdiv class=\"item\"\u003e\u003ca class=\"item-avatar\" href=\"/analytics/Jj83xA-DNyhmN2Iy/card\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u003cimg alt=\"Логотип Телеграм канала t.me/joinchat/Jj83xA-DNyhmN2Iy. Бесплатная аналитика Telegram каналов\" data-src=\"/analytics/images/channels%2F2698aa97db05662f865878a1504c808f.jpg\" title=\"Логотип Телеграм канала \u0026quot;NFT головного мозга\u0026quot;. Бесплатная аналитика Telegram каналов\" /\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info-title\"\u003e\u003ci class=\"icon verification-check disabled\"\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\u003ci class=\"icon teleg disabled\"\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\u003ca href=\"/analytics/Jj83xA-DNyhmN2Iy/card\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eNFT головного мозга\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003ca class=\"item-info-link\" href=\"https://t.me/joinchat/Jj83xA-DNyhmN2Iy\" target=\"_blank\"\u003et.me/joinchat/Jj83xA-DNyhmN2Iy\u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info-text\"\u003eВладелец: @andrey_mnft\nПо рекламе: @shilova_evgeniya\n\nМенеджер без оплаты — @longdxyz\nМенеджер без оплаты - @maximroshkov\n\nДля друга: https://t.me/+Jj83xA-DNyhmN2Iy\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info-theme\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"/analytics/themes/cryptocurrencies\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eКриптовалюты\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help\" title=\"\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Подписчики\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt; Количество людей, подписанных на канал\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eПодписчики:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e1.35M\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help\" title=\"Среднее к-во просмотров одной публикации\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eПросмотры:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e0\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"ER = (Средний охват одного поста / Количество подписчиков) * 100%\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eER:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e0%\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"Стоимость 1000 просмотров в текущей категории\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eCPM:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text text_price\"\u003e\u003cspan class='amount ru'\u003e7 160\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"b-rub\"\u003e₽\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"Fair Value (CPM) - Справедливая стоимость, рассчитанная по параметру CPM. FV CPM (справедливая стоимость по CPM) = APV (Охват) / 1000 * CPM\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eFV (CPM):\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"value\"\u003en/a\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Упоминания\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;Общее количество упоминаний в Телеграм-каналах и внешних ресурсах\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eУпоминания:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e5\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item js_show_more\"\u003e\u003cspan data-less=\"Показывать меньше\" data-more=\"Показать больше\"\u003e\u003ci class=\"icon keyboard_arrow font-20px\"\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item\"\u003e\u003ca class=\"item-avatar\" href=\"/analytics/hueviyherson/card\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u003cimg alt=\"Логотип Телеграм канала @hueviyherson. Бесплатная аналитика Telegram каналов\" data-src=\"https://cdn4.telegram-cdn.org/file/kuipZeaifRrCNhKQHkNSXTwdjOTs2LUVKeIWzUZ-2ikfSysZxq0bwk5A5uWI2zp6-NbLRiMxXONUrv6PXwBoCEjxehYNGd1ZJtDL4u9G7_ObBewRDh3yzj8aKZ9gXQn49NJ_M1Cpflt2GkT_Y6_s5oTO1ezEr7mbibL_7QjW2eNRvIqx_hrPyOhKAP9ygn1-Bw714RkQ9gP8pQpZYDJC9H9dLFFdIqjJ-hCF2JHuaFnAH0apC_-hVtGlXK5uoAYQx4wWGlIj8vEXhYIeixGS1sK2FiwZ2uuK7GeBAUCkZgFLS9Df6y3yXTMp4uH1-5bs00RVFfwiWj2FxtkiY0zdwg.jpg\" title=\"Логотип Телеграм канала \u0026quot;Х*евый Херсон\u0026quot;. Бесплатная аналитика Telegram каналов\" /\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info-title\"\u003e\u003ci class=\"icon verification-check disabled\"\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\u003ci class=\"icon teleg disabled\"\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\u003ca href=\"/analytics/hueviyherson/card\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eХ*евый Херсон\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003ca class=\"item-info-link\" href=\"https://telega.in/tme/hueviyherson\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e@hueviyherson\u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info-text\"\u003eНовости Херсона\n\nСсылка для друзей https://t.me/hueviyherson\n\nприслать новость @hueviy_kherson_Bot\n\nтолько по рекламе @zakaz_addbot\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info-theme\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"/analytics/themes/cryptocurrencies\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eКриптовалюты\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help\" title=\"\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Подписчики\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt; Количество людей, подписанных на канал\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eПодписчики:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e294K\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help\" title=\"Среднее к-во просмотров одной публикации\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eПросмотры:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e143K\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"ER = (Средний охват одного поста / Количество подписчиков) * 100%\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eER:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e49.08%\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"Стоимость 1000 просмотров в текущей категории\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eCPM:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text text_price\"\u003e\u003cspan class='amount ru'\u003e7 160\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"b-rub\"\u003e₽\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"Fair Value (CPM) - Справедливая стоимость, рассчитанная по параметру CPM. FV CPM (справедливая стоимость по CPM) = APV (Охват) / 1000 * CPM\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eFV (CPM):\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"value\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"text_price\"\u003e\u003cspan class='amount ru'\u003e1 023 147\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"b-rub\"\u003e₽\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Упоминания\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;Общее количество упоминаний в Телеграм-каналах и внешних ресурсах\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eУпоминания:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e166\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item js_show_more\"\u003e\u003cspan data-less=\"Показывать меньше\" data-more=\"Показать больше\"\u003e\u003ci class=\"icon keyboard_arrow font-20px\"\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item\"\u003e\u003ca class=\"item-avatar\" href=\"/analytics/bitkogan/card\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u003cimg alt=\"Логотип Телеграм канала @bitkogan. Бесплатная аналитика Telegram каналов\" data-src=\"https://cdn4.telegram-cdn.org/file/BgVWVTR5aR_ySZZ2UHC-sXytZJ5K6dN3TsFY67f5slP7g46YTgpt22WvYcDn4HwTkG51Kh-C0-FjIk8PAeUA5FoGdFxxLf9kaodLczU5ODztRemA2lM3sAGQ2khShH4Hm5vQeErrQ7Hmz8N1l5i6HU03rf5yZgChJM0vfE3IK27ueG6ithMLuIjUqj4va9I_bN7_QBRGsepgz9-scZfIZVvQOEWhVzqW_n5zX3ykdkTw08o3QqKmTvsV3jMmcX5LgAWDGqmhmyC2Bty4j3uiSg61VzJ86DDuUlKeruO-14cNINWzyKUJtfNmxoNuPhURLQqi-aj7VA6zbq8o5vPtZQ.jpg\" title=\"Логотип Телеграм канала \u0026quot;bitkogan\u0026quot;. Бесплатная аналитика Telegram каналов\" /\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info-title\"\u003e\u003ci class=\"icon verification-check disabled\"\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\u003ci class=\"icon teleg disabled\"\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\u003ca href=\"/analytics/bitkogan/card\" target=\"_blank\"\u003ebitkogan\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003ca class=\"item-info-link\" href=\"https://telega.in/tme/bitkogan\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e@bitkogan\u003c/a\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info-text\"\u003eАвторский канал Евгения Когана.\nО деньгах и всем, что с ними связано.\n\nНаписать Евгению: @askbitkogan\nРеклама и PR: @ketkos\nПо бизнес-вопросам: @bitkogans\n\nОнлайн-лекции: https://2stocks.ru/speakers/evgeniy-kogan\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-info-theme\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"/analytics/themes/cryptocurrencies\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eКриптовалюты\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help\" title=\"\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Подписчики\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt; Количество людей, подписанных на канал\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eПодписчики:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e260K\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help\" title=\"Среднее к-во просмотров одной публикации\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eПросмотры:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e56.3K\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"ER = (Средний охват одного поста / Количество подписчиков) * 100%\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eER:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e21.81%\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"Стоимость 1000 просмотров в текущей категории\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eCPM:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text text_price\"\u003e\u003cspan class='amount ru'\u003e7 160\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"b-rub\"\u003e₽\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"Fair Value (CPM) - Справедливая стоимость, рассчитанная по параметру CPM. FV CPM (справедливая стоимость по CPM) = APV (Охват) / 1000 * CPM\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eFV (CPM):\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"value\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"text_price\"\u003e\u003cspan class='amount ru'\u003e403 101\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"b-rub\"\u003e₽\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Упоминания\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;Общее количество упоминаний в Телеграм-каналах и внешних ресурсах\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eУпоминания:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e2 \u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Упоминания\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;Общее количество упоминаний в Телеграм-class=\"title\"\u003eFV (CPM):\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"value\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"text_price\"\u003e\u003cspan class='amount ru'\u003e38 663\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"b-rub\"\u003e₽\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item tooltip-top cursor-help hide\" title=\"\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Упоминания\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;Общее количество упоминаний в Телеграм-каналах и внешних ресурсах\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003eУпоминания:\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"text\"\u003e8\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"item-stat-item js_show_more\"\u003e\u003cspan data-less=\"Показывать меньше\" data-more=\"Показать больше\"\u003e\u003ci class=\"icon keyboard_arrow font-20px\"\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e","show_more_btn":true}
```

Мне необходимо вытащить ВСЕ значения после Словосочетания: "Логотип Телеграм канала" до точки.

Делаю так, но разумеется неправильно, иначе не обращался бы:

```
preg_match('/[Логотип Телеграм канала ]\s+([^\n]+)',$page['content'], $match);
```

Помогите пожалуйста составить правильно регулярку.

Comment: может начать надо с того, чтобы к вашему исходному тексту применить json_decode?

Comment: @teran зачем? Вон чел в ответе регуляркой спокойно пилит и не парится (уже не первый ответ такой и говорит что так всю жизнь делает и работает). Так что кому ваши непонятные жисоны нужны ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @teran а что это даст? в json я вижу все равно два элемента, и надо разбирать `['html']`. Можно сплитить по фразе, а потом по точке с пробелом дабы получить то что автору нужно. А можно написать регулярку, что имхо оптимальнее и проще..запрос написанный в ответе исполняется 0.5мс, что по сравнению с получением данных(сам json получить по запросу) мизер неимоверный (100-150мс).

Comment: @Андрюха даст нормальные данные, а не экранированную jsonом часть строки

Comment: @teran да, согласен, толк есть.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

попробуйте так.

```
$text=json_decode($page['content']);
preg_match_all("/Логотип Телеграм канала\s+(.+)\.\s/U",$text->html,$mth);
print_r($mth[1]);
```

В итоге массив содержащий все вхождения после данной фразы до точки с пробелом.